# Tricky Optics Questions, shifting lenses

Tags: optics, visible-light, lenses

A candle is placed at a fixed distance in front of a
wall. A lens is inserted and moved slowly between
them. At two particular positions, sharp images
are formed on the wall. The heights of the images
are 50 cm and 8 cm respectively. What is the
height of the candle?

I've been pondering this over the past hour, and I still can't think of a good way to solve this. I've tried using similar triangles and other trigonometric methods but nothing seems to work. Does anybody have an alternative method?

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please note that Physics.StackExchange is not a homework help site. Please read [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, the lens equation is symmetric:  if an object at distance $A$ forms a real image at distance $B$, then an object at distance $B$ forms a real image at distance $A$.  So, for the system you describe, the image and object distances simply swap roles without changing size.

Secondly, the magnification, by the similar triangles you mention, is given by the image distance divided by the object distance. So, the above paragraph implies that the magnifications for the two situations are reciprocals.

Consider the two situations described, with $x$ the object height and $M_1$ and $M_2$ the two magnifications:$$M_1 = \frac{8}{x}$$ $$M_2=\frac{50}x$$ $$\frac{1}{M_2}=M_1$$ $$\frac{x}{50}=\frac8x$$ Solve for $x$...

Comment: Ok never mind, I got it. I really wasn't thinking. Thanks a lot for your answer!